# Leetcode 1275. Find Winner on a Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on one easy question ([Leetcode 1275. Find Winner on a Tic Tac Toe Game](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-winner-on-a-tic-tac-toe-game/submissions/)) and am wondering how I can make the code even cleaner.

```
class Solution:
    def tictactoe(self, moves: List[List[int]]) -> str:
        from collections import Counter

        def is_win(pos: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
            pos = set(tuple(i) for i in pos)
            d1, d2 = set([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]), set([(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)])
            x = Counter(i for i, _ in pos)
            y = Counter(i for _, i in pos)
            d1 -= set(pos)
            d2 -= set(pos)
            return (3 in x.values()) or (3 in y.values()) or not d1 or not d2

        a, b = moves[::2], moves[1::2]
        A, B = is_win(a), is_win(b)
        if A:
            return 'A'
        elif B:
            return 'B'
        elif not A and not B and (len(moves) == 9):
            return 'Draw'
        return 'Pending'
```

Comment: Can you add a context of calling your function `tictactoe` with sample value for `moves` ?

Comment: Yep, using `List[int]` instead of the more obvious `Tuple[int, int]` for `(row, col)` is definitely confusing. Leetcode should have defined better types here.

Answer (score 1):

The second half of your code is inefficient, as it computers `is_win(b)` unnecessarily. It can be written as:

```py
    if is_win(moves[::2]):
        return 'A'
    elif is_win(moves[1::2]):
        return 'B'
    elif len(moves) == 9:
        return 'Draw'
    else:
        return 'Pending'
```

This removes the redundant `not a and not b`, the redundant parentheses and the redundant computation of `is_win` in case A has won already.

When I saw `is_win` for the first time, I didn't understand it.

- Maybe my chances had been better if you renamed `d1` to `diag1`.
- You could also write `diag1` and `diag2` on separate lines, to align their coordinates vertically.
- You could also inline the `diag1` and `diag2` so that you don't need a name for them at all.

I'm thinking of:

```py
def is_win(pos: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    pos = set(tuple(i) for i in pos)
    horiz = 3 in Counter(r for r, _ in pos).values()
    verti = 3 in Counter(c for _, c in pos).values()
    diag1 = not (set([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]) - pos)
    diag2 = not (set([(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)]) - pos)
    return horiz or verti or diag1 or diag2
```

To avoid unnecessary computations here as well, you can let your IDE inline the variables except for `pos`.

Instead of `not (set1 - set2)`, the expression `set1.issubset(set2)` is clearer because it avoids the confusing `not`:

```py
    diag1 = {(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)}.issubset(pos)
    # or:
    diag1 = {(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)} <= pos
```

Or you could make checking the diagonals similar to horizontal and vertical:

```py
    diag1 = 3 in Counter(r - c for r, c in pos).values()
    diag2 = 3 in Counter(r + c for r, c in pos).values()
```

Comment: it is good idea to use multiple list comprehensive other than just use one for loop?